# Create .NET assembly connector programmatically in SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Does anybody know how to create a .NET assembly connector programmatically? I mean I want to generate an .NET assembly in runtime using Reflection.Emit and deploy it to SharePoint.

I've found this great post:

http://www.toddbaginski.com/blog/archive/2009/12/01/how-to-programmatically-create-a-sharepoint-2010-external-content-type.aspx

where a database external type is created, but I need to create an external type based on a .NET assembly

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer to your question, but just an observation/suggestion. In order to deploy an assembly that SharePoint will use you have to get it in the GAC.  I would think if you created some code to Emit the assembly then had either your current app or another app create a PowerShell script to add the assembly to the GAC and wire up all the SharePoint STSADM stuff, then you could accomplish what you want. I may have better ideas with more details of where you are generating the new assembly (from some external app, etc). Hope this helps or at least sparks some ideas.

Comment: You don't have to put an assembly in the GAC - it can also go in the BIN dir.

Comment: True, you can place it in the bin, but then you have to put it in the bin for all servers. Either way works, there are advantages and disadvantages to each.